# UseFieldArray - Trying to Append objects based on array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

I am using UseFieldArray from React hook form to generate a dynamic form. I have two use cases

1-Add
2-Edit

3 Components are involved in this.

Code is working fine in Add use case. But when I am trying to open the same in Edit mode my approach is to pass the array of nested objects as props to child components and append them  while mapping through them.

**Parent Component**

```
export default function BookingTest() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const methods = useForm<BookingDto>();
    const params = useParams();
    console.log(params.id);
    const {
        data: getBookingData,
        error: getBookingError,
        loading: getBookingLoading,
    } = useGetByIdBookingQuery({
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables: {
            id: params.id || ' ',
        },
    });
    useApiExceptionHandler({ error: getBookingError });

    const bookingDto = useMemo(() => getBookingData?.booking, [getBookingData?.booking]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (bookingDto != null) {
            methods.setValue('bookingDate', bookingDto?.bookingDate || '', { shouldValidate: true });
            methods.setValue('bookingNumber', bookingDto?.bookingNumber || '', { shouldValidate: true });
        }
    }, [methods.setValue, bookingDto, methods]);

    const [createBookingMutation] = useCreateBookingViaFormMutation();
    const onSubmit = async (request: BookingDto) => {
        try {
            console.log(request);
            const response = await createBookingMutation({
                variables: {
                    bookingInput: {
                        bookingNumber: request.bookingNumber,
                        customerId: '10000',
                        bookingDate: request.bookingDate,
                        bookingLines: request.bookingLines,
                    },
                },
            });
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data?.createBooking.id != null) {
                toast.success('Booking Created Successfully');
                navigate('/Bookings/manage');
            }
            return;
        } catch (error: any) {
            toast.error('User Creation Failed. ' + error?.message);
            return;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <FormProvider {...methods}>
                <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <RoundedBox>
                        <div className="space-y-6 bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:p-6">
                            <label htmlFor="role" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                General
                            </label>

                            <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                                <div className="col-span-2 sm:col-span-2">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={'bookingDate'}
                                        control={methods.control}
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <DatePickerComponent
                                                format={'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'}
                                                {...field}
                                                placeholder="Booking Date"
                                                style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}
                                            ></DatePickerComponent>
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-span-2 sm:col-span-2">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={'bookingNumber'}
                                        control={methods.control}
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <InputText
                                                label="Booking Number"
                                                className="e-input"
                                                required={true}
                                                register={methods.register('bookingNumber')}
                                                name="input"
                                                type="text"
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {/* <FormErrorList className="pl-4" errors={errors} /> */}
                        </div>
                    </RoundedBox>
                    <br></br>

                    {getBookingLoading && <BookingLine bookingLineDtos={bookingDto?.bookingLines as any} />}
                    {/* <br></br>
                    <BookingLineEntries /> */}

                    <div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 text-right sm:px-6">
                        <Button submit color="primary">
                            Create
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </FormProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Child Component**

```
interface myProps {
    bookingLineDtos: Array<BookingLineDto>;
}
const BookingLine: React.FC<myProps> = ({ bookingLineDtos }) => {
    const { control, register, watch, getValues } = useFormContext<BookingDto>();

    const { fields, append, prepend, remove, swap, move, insert } = useFieldArray<BookingDto, 'bookingLines', 'id'>({
        control,
        name: 'bookingLines',
        keyName: 'id',
    });

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     console.log({ bookingLineDtos });
    // }, [bookingLineDtos]);

    useEffect(() => {
        bookingLineDtos?.map(function (item, i) {
            append(item);
        });
    }, [bookingLineDtos, insert]);

    return (
        <>
            <RoundedBox>
                <div className="space-y-6 bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:p-6">
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="role" className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                            Booking Lines
                        </label>
                        <button type="button" style={{ float: 'right' }} onClick={() => append({})}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCirclePlus} />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </RoundedBox>
            <br></br>

            {fields.map((item, index) => (
                <>
                    <RoundedBox>
                        <div className="space-y-6 bg-white px-4 py-5 sm:p-6">
                            <div>
                                <label htmlFor="role" className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                    Booking Lines - {index + 1}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                                <div className="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={`bookingLines.${index}.status`}
                                        control={control}
                                        defaultValue={item.status}
                                        render={({ field }) => <InputText required={true} {...field} label="Status" type="text" />}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={`bookingLines.${index}.type`}
                                        control={control}
                                        defaultValue={item.type}
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <InputSelect
                                                required={true}
                                                {...field}
                                                name={`bookingLines.${index}.type`}
                                                style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}
                                                dataSource={[
                                                    { Id: 'Inbound', Value: 'Inbound' },
                                                    { Id: 'Outbound', Value: 'Outbound' },
                                                ]}
                                                defaultValue={item.type}
                                                fields={{ value: 'Id', text: 'Value' }}
                                                placeholder="Select Trip Type"
                                                label="Trip Type"
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                
                                <div className="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={`bookingLines.${index}.transportationType`}
                                        control={control}
                                        defaultValue={item.transportationType}
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <InputSelect
                                                required={true}
                                                {...field}
                                                name={`bookingLines.${index}.transportationType`}
                                                style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}
                                                dataSource={[
                                                    { Id: 'Seaplane Transfer', Value: 'Seaplane Transfer' },
                                                    { Id: 'Seaplane Charter', Value: 'Seaplane Charter' },
                                                    { Id: 'Wheelplane Transfer', Value: 'Wheelplane Transfer' },
                                                    { Id: 'Wheelplane Charter', Value: 'Wheelplane Charter' },
                                                    { Id: 'Boat Transfer', Value: 'Boat Transfer' },
                                                ]}
                                                defaultValue={item.transportationType}
                                                fields={{ value: 'Id', text: 'Value' }}
                                                placeholder="Select Transportation Type"
                                                label="Transportation Type"
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>

                            <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                                <div className="col-span-2 sm:col-span-2">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={`bookingLines.${index}.departureDateTime`}
                                        control={control}
                                        defaultValue={item.departureDateTime}
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <DatePickerComponent
                                                format={'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'}
                                                {...field}
                                                placeholder="Departure Date"
                                                style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}
                                            ></DatePickerComponent>
                                        )}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                {/* <div className="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={`bookingLines.${index}.totalSeats`}
                                        control={control}
                                        defaultValue={item.totalSeats}
                                        render={({ field }) => <InputText {...field} label="Total Seats" type="number" />}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-span-1 sm:col-span-1">
                                    <Controller
                                        name={`bookingLines.${index}.totalWeight`}
                                        control={control}
                                        defaultValue={item.totalWeight}
                                        render={({ field }) => <InputText {...field} label="Total Weight" type="number" />}
                                    />
                                </div> */}
                            </div>
                            <button style={{ float: 'right' }} type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleMinus} />
                            </button>
                            {/* <FormErrorList className="pl-4" errors={errors} /> */}
                            <br></br>
                            <br></br>
                            <div>
                                <BookingLineEntries tripIndex={index} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </RoundedBox>
                    <br></br>
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
export default BookingLine;
```

The problem is:

**My Child component is ending up being called TWICE When I am mapping through the props array. when there is only one object in the array.**

I am quite newbie to the react so let me know if I can add/ need more details on it. Thank you in advance.